# custom uitabbar subclass uitabbarcontroller or develop custom view?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitabbarcontroller, custom-controls, uitabbar

I am developing an application for iOS 4 based iphone/ipad, required to develop custom UITabBar for my application. as per specification, The tab-bar has
1. image as background
2. tabbar items as custom buttons 
3. buttons having badges

Please refer the image:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/638/tabbar.jpg/

It is not required to bring any views corresponding to the click of buttons. so is it advisable to
a. subclass uitabbar controller OR
b. make a view with custom buttons having badges?

Please share your thoughts, alternative approach and code snippet if possible.
Thanks and Regards,
powerpc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not bringing on any views, you are most probably looking for a **toolbar** rather than a tab bar.

After looking at your image I recommend rolling your own with `UIView`.

However, if you need advanced tab bar functionality, such as managing the items and badges, you can also subclass `UITabBar`. After all it is also a subclass of `UIView`.

Comment: thanks mundi, but the functionality i am looking seems exactly what a tabbar provides, for ex. badge, tabbaritems etc. so isn't subclassing a uitabbar a good idea?

Comment: for custom uiview, i would have to make a badge class of my own, link it to my custom button. and the custom button would be attached to uiview. also badge have to be updated periodically as and when user goes online,offline,busy.

Comment: Do you need to manage more than 5 items in the tab bar? In this case you would be right. As for the badge, I thought you want your custom badge anyway, as your image showed various sizes of badges...